# Why does the shape and size of an array part deforming when using curve modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, curve-modifier

So basically im trying to make a tiled roof top thats curved. Simple deform doesnt do what i want so i want to use a curve modifier however whenever i add the curve modifier to the array the size of the array changes and looks terrible.

Here are the steps i took:
1.Made the part i want
2.fixed its rotation
3. Set all transforms on the part
4.added array to increase number of parts
5.Made the curve i want
6. Moves it to world origin
7. Set all transforms for the curve
8.moved part to world origin so they both have the same origin
9. Set all transforms for both just incase
10. Added curve modifier
11. Terrible results parts become bigger and are flying above curve not on it

Where did i go wrong? Please help me ive been stuck for weeks
[image: Before curve modifier]

[image: After curve modifier]

Answer (score 1):

Yes i see your problem , here is the solution :
Create the mesh you wanna repeat , the curve , move everything to world origin .
Create a plane , re-size it to kinda fit the size of the mesh ( the size of the plane not really essential ) , apply the *scale* of the plane and the mesh .
Move the plane to the same location of the mesh
Select the mesh , select the plane , hit *CTRL+P* , select *Object* .
Now go to the plane *Object properties* ( the yellow triangle in the toolbar menu ) , go to *Instancing* , select *Faces* , in the same Propoerties , go to *Visibility* , *Show in* , and disable *viewport* and *render* .
Now you're good to go , apply the array and curve modifier and you wont have any deformation .